# Python -- Function Decorator results in function being called twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am using a function decorator in some unit tests that I am writing to test code. However, I have figured out that this decorator causes the function to be called twice (and therefore print its output twice).

I figured out this error after some functions were returning errant return values that would only happen if a function was called twice.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def decorate(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("#" * 40)
        print("Testing function {}".format(func.__name__))
        print("Arguments passed: {} ".format(args))
        print("Begin output of {}".format(func.__name__))
        print("#" * 40)
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error occured: {}".format(e))

        print("#" * 40)
        print("End of output of {}".format(func.__name__))
        print("#" * 40)
        print("\n" * 5)
        return func(*args,**kwargs) #Error happens on this line here
    return inner

#Add decorator to function definition. 
@decorate
def asdf():
    print("THIS SHOULD PRINT ONCE")

#Call function

asdf()
```

Output (spacing exactly as copied):

```
########################################
Testing function asdf
Arguments passed: ()
Begin output of asdf
########################################
THIS SHOULD PRINT ONCE
########################################
End of output of asdf
########################################






THIS SHOULD PRINT ONCE
```

My desired output:

```
########################################
Testing function asdf
Arguments passed: ()
Begin output of asdf
########################################
THIS SHOULD PRINT ONCE
########################################
End of output of asdf
########################################
```

I am trying to eliminate the second calling of the function. I know my error lies in the decorator, I just cannot find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that you are **calling** the function twice from inside the decorator:

- Once in the `try/except` block.
- and once at the return statement.

You would want to change the first call (the one in the try block) to:

```py
res = func(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then simply:

```py
return res
```

---

**EDIT**: (according to @DanielRoseman's comment)

Since you are not raising or returning from the `except` block, you have to either assign `res` also there (inside the `except`) or alternativly pre-define it at the start of the decorator to `None` (or whatever value fits your program).

Comment: Although they will need to define a default value for res in the `except` block, as otherwise it wouldn't be defined if the can raised an exception

Answer (score 4):

You make the call twice, indeed, here in boldface:

```
def decorate(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("#" * 40)
        print("Testing function {}".format(func.__name__))
        print("Arguments passed: {} ".format(args))
        print("Begin output of {}".format(func.__name__))
        print("#" * 40)
        try:
            func(*args,**kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error occured: {}".format(e))

        print("#" * 40)
        print("End of output of {}".format(func.__name__))
        print("#" * 40)
        print("\n" * 5)
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return inner
```

You probably want to omit one of the two, and store the result in a temporary variable, like:

```
def decorate(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("#" * 40)
        print("Testing function {}".format(func.__name__))
        print("Arguments passed: {} ".format(args))
        print("Begin output of {}".format(func.__name__))
        print("#" * 40)
        try:
            result = func(*args,**kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error occured: {}".format(e))
            result = None

        print("#" * 40)
        print("End of output of {}".format(func.__name__))
        print("#" * 40)
        print("\n" * 5)
        return result
    return inner
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was an error in how I was returning the function, I just wasn't sure how.